# Add Length Property to Select

Tags: sql, select, powershell, properties

Newbie here...everyone's help and input is greatly appreciated!

30,000' view: Create Report on "stale data" that can/should be deleted from network.

Step 1. Gather list of folders that begin with either "ST_" or "EDDS1" from a group of servers that includes the FullName, Name & Length values.

```
$Path = 
"\\server1.domain.com\b\sqlbackups",
"\\server1.domain.com\b\sqlbackups",
"\\server1.domain.com\b\sqlbackups";

$BackupFolders = @(gci $Path -filter "ST_*" | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer}) | Select FullName,Name,Length
$BackupFolders += @(gci $Path -filter "EDDS1*" | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer}) | Select-Object FullName Name, Length

$BackupFolders | Export-CSV C:\BackupFolders.csv
```

This pulls in a column for length but there are no values listed in that colum...

Step 2. Compare this list to SQL table. If value exists in reference doc (Step 1) & in a specific colum in SQL, then look at "status tab" in SQL. If the SQL table "status tab" indicates "inactive", output FullName, Name, Length from Step1 and Client, Project Name from SQL table into csv.

```
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=sqlserver\sharename;Database=database;Integrated Security=True"
$sqlConnection.Open()

$sqlCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Table].[dbo].[Matters] WHERE [Status] NOT LIKE 'Active%'"
$sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
$sqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$sqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $sqlCommand
$Dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$sqlAdapter.Fill($Dataset)
$sqlConnection.Close()

$MatterStatus = @"
C:\MatterStatus.csv
"@

$Dataset.Tables[0] | Select Client,Project,MatterStatus | Export-Csv c:\MatterStatus.csv
```

Question1 - How do I get the Length Attribute to be listed in my csv created from Step1?

Question2 - Am I on the right track here? Same as Step1, the last value did not propagate...MatterStatus in my csv is blank.

Any suggestions/hints are much appreciated!

Comment: You must work at a law firm. The Length object on a directory is always blank. You would have to walk all the sub-folders in the directory and add up the length of all the files to get the sive of the directory.

Comment: What do you mean by "Length" ?

Comment: EBGreen - not a law firm EE. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Eris - I am trying to get the folder size of all the separate folders in my $Path..

Answer (score 0):

According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730945.aspx, you can use `gci | Measure-Object` or the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` COM object to get the folder size.

Solution 1 (Pure Powershell):

```
Function Get-ItemSize($Path) {
    (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path:$Path | Measure-Object -Property:Length -Sum | Select -ExpandProperty:Sum) / 1MB
}
```

Solution 2 (COM Object):

```
$objFSO = New-Object -com  Scripting.FileSystemObject
Function Get-ItemSize($Path) {
    ($objFSO.GetFolder($Path).Size) / 1MB
}
```

Combined with calculated properties, you can replace

```
... | Select FullName, Name, Length
```

With:

```
... | Select FullName, Name, @{Name='Length'; @Expression= {"{0:N2} MB" -f (Get-ItemSize($_) })
```

They provide identical output:

```
PS> Get-item 'D:\Temp' | Select FullName, Name, @{ Name='Length'; Expression = { "{0:N2} MB" -f (Get-ItemSize($_)) } }

FullName                                 Name                                     Length                                 
--------                                 ----                                     ------                                 
D:\Temp                                  Temp                                     58.28 MB
```

I'm going to guess the COM object is technically faster, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader.